# Select all items in checkbox group with CSJS?

Tags: xpages

I am able to select all of the items in a checkbox group with SSJS by simply setting the component's value.

But how would I do this in CSJS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the name of your check box group is `checkBoxGroup` this code snippet of check all checkbox should do the trick for you.

```
<xp:checkBox text="Check all" id="chkCheckAll">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[dojo.query("input[name=\"#{id:checkBoxGroup}\"]").forEach(
    function(node) {
        node.checked = document.getElementById("#{id:chkCheckAll}").checked;
    }
)]]></xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:checkBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

You select them with `dojo.query` and set the selected property to true. You need to check: every box will have its own ID, but the beginning of it is the same -or- you use a class. Or you look for the first and then select all siblings.

The strategy depends on your application's needs.

Check the [dojo.query](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.6/dojo/query.html) documentation for your options.

Answer (score 1):

this is how you do it in jquery

```
$("[name$=checkBoxGroup1]").attr("checked",true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying Naveen's answer, this worked great for me:

```
dojo.query("input[name=\"#{id:checkBoxGroup1}\"]").forEach( function(node) {
        node.checked = true; 
    });
```