# how to select all values of checkbox group using "select All" option - lotus Xpages

Tags: checkbox, xpages-ssjs

I am working with my Xpages application. I have a checkbox group.  can some one help in finding me a way out to select all options of checkbox Group through a select all option .or any workarround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've tagged the question with xpages-ssjs, so I have a solution for that, although it would be more efficient to do this client side. A client side solution would can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12963732/select-all-items-in-checkbox-group-with-csjs).

```
<xp:panel id="root">
        <xp:checkBoxGroup id="checkBoxGroup1">
            <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Option A" itemValue="1"></xp:selectItem>
            <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Option B" itemValue="2"></xp:selectItem>
            <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Option C" itemValue="3"></xp:selectItem>
            <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Option D" itemValue="4"></xp:selectItem>
        </xp:checkBoxGroup>
        <xp:button value="Check all" id="button1">
            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                execId="panel" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="root">
                <xp:this.action>
                    <xp:executeScript>
                        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[#{javascript:
            var group = getComponent("checkBoxGroup1")
            var checkboxChildren = group.getChildren();
            var values = new Array();
            for (i = 0; i < checkboxChildren.length; i++ ){
                values.push(  checkboxChildren[i].getItemValue()) ;
            }
            getComponent("checkBoxGroup1").setValue( values );

}]]></xp:this.script>
                    </xp:executeScript>
                </xp:this.action>
            </xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:button>
    </xp:panel>
```